# What does PARTITION BY 1 mean?

Tags: oracle, count, analytics, database-partitioning

For a pair of cursors where the total number of rows in the resultset is required immediately after the first FETCH, ( after some trial-and-error ) I came up with the query below

```
SELECT
 col_a,
 col_b,
 col_c,
 COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY 1 ) AS rows_in_result
FROM 
 myTable JOIN theirTable ON
 myTable.col_a = theirTable.col_z
GROUP BY
 col_a, col_b, col_c
ORDER BY 
 col_b
```

Now when the output of the query is X rows, rows_in_result reflects this accurately.

- What does PARTITION BY 1 mean?

  - I *think* it probably tells the database to partition the results into pieces of 1-row each

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is an unusual use of PARTITION BY.  What it does is put everything into the same partition so that if the query returns 123 rows altogether, then the value of rows_in_result on each row will be 123 (as its alias implies).

It is therefore equivalent to the more concise:

```
COUNT(*) OVER ()
```

Answer (score 5):

Databases are quite free to add restrictions to the `OVER()` clause. Sometimes, either `PARTITION BY [...]` and/or `ORDER BY [...]` are mandatory clauses, depending on the aggregate function. `PARTITION BY 1` may just be a dummy clause used for syntax integrity. The following two are usually equivalent:

```
[aggregate function] OVER ()
[aggregate function] OVER (PARTITION BY 1)
```

Note, though, that Sybase SQL Anywhere and [CUBRID](http://jira.cubrid.org/browse/ENGINE-85) interpret this `1` as being a column index reference, similar to what is possible in the `ORDER BY [...]` clause. This might appear to be a bit surprising as it imposes an evaluation order to the query's projection. In your case, this *would then* mean that the following are equivalent

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col_a)
```

This curious deviation from other databases' interpretation allows for referencing more complex grouping expressions.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: I've seen your comment on a deleted answer. As a matter of fact, unfortunately, and to my own surprise, there *are* different ways of interpreting this simple expression.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Your original (now deleted) answer was wrong for Oracle, but correct for other databases...